# How to popup a transparent Panel that is dismissed when clicked outside of it in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I need to popup some buttons in Flex 4.  Users should be able to see the background (ideally a little faded, but not important) around and in between the buttons.  And clicking anywhere except the buttons should dismiss them all.

So I created a spark `Panel` and added a spark `VGroup` with some buttons.  Then I call

```
PopupManager.addPopUp(myNewPanel, background, true);
```

My 2 main problems are the panel is not transparent and clicking outside the buttons doesn't dismiss them...  How do I implement that?

***UPDATE***: Figured out how to dismiss the popup when clicking outside the panel with:

```
    addEventListener("mouseDownOutside", close);

    private function close(event:FlexMouseEvent):void {
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
    }
```

Now I just need to figure out how to make the Panel transparent so you can see the background around and in between the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use FlexMouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN_OUTSIDE instead of the string "mouseDownOutside". Code completion, compile-time checking and makes it easier for others to read your code.

For the background, you can use css to style it. Heres a list of all the css properties for a spark panel - http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/Panel.html#styleSummary

Comment: Thank you greg!  the constant vs the string makes sense of course, changed that.  Was able to do the backgroundAlpha="0", works great.  Everything is as I want it, except there's a bar at the top of the panel which doesn't disappear :(.  I assume it's the controlBar, but it remains even with controlBarVisible="false".  Any ideas?

Comment: related to stack overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147884/click-outside-event-on-custom-components-in-flex